# How does GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() work? (MVC5)

Tags: oauth, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, asp.net-identity-2

I have a very simple question, some time of Googling didn't give me the answer. I'm using MVC 5 for a project and using OWIN OAuth features for facebook login.

I'm using the recommended way by first creating a challange result:

```
return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
```

and in a callback function capturing it with

```
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

Now my question is, is this the only that this method (GetExternalLoginInfoAsync) works? I need to access the info (loginInfo) provided by this callback later on, should I write this to a db, etc or is there a better way?